# Using jQuery to bump list item to right on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to bring a little more attention to the list item being hovered by "bumping" the text a little to the right then back again when hovered over. This is what I have:

```
$('.ipro_menu ul li a').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        'padding-left':'20px'},100,function(){
            $(this).animate({
                'padding-left':'15px'});
    });
});
```

The padding is originally 15px, so when you hover over a link in the list, the padding increases by 5px, then quickly goes back to 15px again. The problem is that it is moving more than one element at a time. Sometimes it moves not only itself, but also the item above or below it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can we see your HTML?  jsfiddle is good for these types of questions too.

Comment: Maybe try `text-indent` instead of `padding`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The padding is originally 15px, so when you hover over a link in the list, the padding increases by 5px, then **quickly goes back** to 15px again

So basically you want a bounce effect? If so:

```
var cssOver = { 'padding-left': '25px' },
      cssOut = { 'padding-left': '15px' },
      overDuration = 100,
      outDuration = 100,
      selector = '.ipro_menu ul li';

  $(selector).mouseover(function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    _this
      .clearQueue()
      .animate(cssOver, overDuration, function(){
        _this.animate(cssOut, outDuration);
      });
  });
```

Live example: http://bl.ocks.org/3077195

Personally I would suggest using this plugin: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Answer (score 6):

I made a quick jsfiddle of what I think you are looking to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/tuXcA/

The code is basically:

```
$('ul').find('li').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'padding-left':'20px'
    },100);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'padding-left':'0px'
    },100);
});
```

Slides right on hover, then slides back to normal position when not hovered.